# Akka.Streams.Kafka - can't load a consumer

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, stream, queue, akka.net

I'm studying Akka.Streams.Kafka (see  examples on the page https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Streams.Kafka) and I've a problem with creating a Consumer configuration

```
public class TestService : IHostedService
{
    private ActorSystem _system;
    private ActorMaterializer _materializer;

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var actorsSetup = BootstrapSetup.Create()
            .WithConfig(HoconLoader.ParseConfig("appsettings.conf"));

        var kafkaConfig = HoconLoader.ParseConfig("kafka.conf");

        _system = ActorSystem.Create("system", actorsSetup);
        _materializer = _system.Materializer();

        var consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings<Null, string>
            .Create(kafkaConfig, null, Deserializers.Utf8)
            .WithBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
            .WithDispatcher("")
            .WithGroupId("group1"); // NULL-REF EXCEPTION HERE!

        await KafkaConsumer.CommittableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.Topics("TestTopic"))
            .SelectAsync(1, async elem =>
            {
                await elem.CommitableOffset.Commit();
                Console.WriteLine($"VAL:{elem.Record?.Value}");
                return Done.Instance;
            })
            .RunWith(Sink.Ignore<Done>(), _materializer);
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _materializer.Shutdown();
        _system.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Despites of (seemingly) correct initialization, I've "NUllReferenceException" when I'm trying to create a `ConsumerSettings` object.

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Сообщение = Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Источник = Akka.Streams.Kafka
  Трассировка стека:
   в Akka.Streams.Kafka.Settings.ConnectionCheckerSettings.Create(Config config)
```

my HOCONS:
appsettings.conf:

```
#####################################
# Akka Stream Reference Config File #
#####################################

akka { 
  stream {

    # Default flow materializer settings
    materializer {

      # Initial size of buffers used in stream elements
      # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in ActorMaterializerSettings
      initial-input-buffer-size = 4

      # Maximum size of buffers used in stream elements
      # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in ActorMaterializerSettings
      max-input-buffer-size = 16

      # Fully qualified config path which holds the dispatcher configuration
      # to be used by FlowMaterialiser when creating Actors.
      # When this value is left empty, the default-dispatcher will be used.
      # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in ActorMaterializerSettings
      dispatcher = ""

      blocking-io-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-blocking-io-dispatcher"

      # Cleanup leaked publishers and subscribers when they are not used within a given
      # deadline
      subscription-timeout {
        # when the subscription timeout is reached one of the following strategies on
        # the "stale" publisher:
        # cancel - cancel it (via `onError` or subscribing to the publisher and
        #          `cancel()`ing the subscription right away
        # warn   - log a warning statement about the stale element (then drop the
        #          reference to it)
        # noop   - do nothing (not recommended)     
        # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in StreamSubscriptionTimeoutSettings
        mode = cancel

        # time after which a subscriber / publisher is considered stale and eligible
        # for cancelation (see `akka.stream.subscription-timeout.mode`)     
        # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in StreamSubscriptionTimeoutSettings
        timeout = 5s
      }
      
      # Enable additional troubleshooting logging at DEBUG log level
      # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in ActorMaterializerSettings
      debug-logging = off

      # Maximum number of elements emitted in batch if downstream signals large demand
      # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in ActorMaterializerSettings
      output-burst-limit = 1000
      
      # Enable automatic fusing of all graphs that are run. For short-lived streams
      # this may cause an initial runtime overhead, but most of the time fusing is
      # desirable since it reduces the number of Actors that are created.
      # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in ActorMaterializerSettings
      auto-fusing = on

      # Those stream elements which have explicit buffers (like mapAsync, mapAsyncUnordered,
      # buffer, flatMapMerge, Source.actorRef, Source.queue, etc.) will preallocate a fixed
      # buffer upon stream materialization if the requested buffer size is less than this
      # configuration parameter. The default is very high because failing early is better
      # than failing under load.
      #
      # Buffers sized larger than this will dynamically grow/shrink and consume more memory
      # per element than the fixed size buffers.
      # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in ActorMaterializerSettings
      max-fixed-buffer-size = 1000000000

      # Maximum number of sync messages that actor can process for stream to substream communication.
      # Parameter allows to interrupt synchronous processing to get upsteam/downstream messages.
      # Allows to accelerate message processing that happening withing same actor but keep system responsive.
      # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in ActorMaterializerSettings
      sync-processing-limit = 1000

      debug {
        # Enables the fuzzing mode which increases the chance of race conditions
        # by aggressively reordering events and making certain operations more
        # concurrent than usual.
        # This setting is for testing purposes, NEVER enable this in a production
        # environment!
        # To get the best results, try combining this setting with a throughput
        # of 1 on the corresponding dispatchers.
        # Note: If you change this value also change the fallback value in ActorMaterializerSettings
        fuzzing-mode = off
      }
      
      stream-ref {
        # Buffer of a SinkRef that is used to batch Request elements from the other side of the stream ref
        #
        # The buffer will be attempted to be filled eagerly even while the local stage did not request elements,
        # because the delay of requesting over network boundaries is much higher.
        buffer-capacity = 32
      
        # Demand is signalled by sending a cumulative demand message ("requesting messages until the n-th sequence number)
        # Using a cumulative demand model allows us to re-deliver the demand message in case of message loss (which should
        # be very rare in any case, yet possible -- mostly under connection break-down and re-establishment).
        #
        # The semantics of handling and updating the demand however are in-line with what Reactive Streams dictates.
        #
        # In normal operation, demand is signalled in response to arriving elements, however if no new elements arrive
        # within `demand-redelivery-interval` a re-delivery of the demand will be triggered, assuming that it may have gotten lost.
        demand-redelivery-interval = 1 second
      
        # Subscription timeout, during which the "remote side" MUST subscribe (materialize) the handed out stream ref.
        # This timeout does not have to be very low in normal situations, since the remote side may also need to
        # prepare things before it is ready to materialize the reference. However the timeout is needed to avoid leaking
        # in-active streams which are never subscribed to.
        subscription-timeout = 30 seconds
        
        # In order to guard the receiving end of a stream ref from never terminating (since awaiting a Completion or Failed
        # message) after / before a Terminated is seen, a special timeout is applied once Terminated is received by it.
        # This allows us to terminate stream refs that have been targeted to other nodes which are Downed, and as such the
        # other side of the stream ref would never send the "final" terminal message.
        #
        # The timeout specifically means the time between the Terminated signal being received and when the local SourceRef
        # determines to fail itself, assuming there was message loss or a complete partition of the completion signal.
        final-termination-signal-deadline = 2 seconds
      }
    }

    # Deprecated, left here to not break Akka HTTP which refers to it
    blocking-io-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-blocking-io-dispatcher"

    # Deprecated, will not be used unless user code refer to it, use 'akka.stream.materializer.blocking-io-dispatcher'
    # instead, or if from code, prefer the 'ActorAttributes.IODispatcher' attribute
    default-blocking-io-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-blocking-io-dispatcher"
  }

  # configure overrides to ssl-configuration here (to be used by akka-streams, and akka-http – i.e. when serving https connections)
  ssl-config {
    protocol = "TLSv1"
  }
  actor {
  
    serializers {
      akka-stream-ref = "Akka.Streams.Serialization.StreamRefSerializer, Akka.Streams"
    }
  
    serialization-bindings {
      "Akka.Streams.Implementation.StreamRef.SinkRefImpl, Akka.Streams"         = akka-stream-ref
      "Akka.Streams.Implementation.StreamRef.SourceRefImpl, Akka.Streams"       = akka-stream-ref
      "Akka.Streams.Implementation.StreamRef.IStreamRefsProtocol, Akka.Streams" = akka-stream-ref
    }
  
    serialization-identifiers {
      "Akka.Streams.Serialization.StreamRefSerializer, Akka.Streams" = 30
    }
  }
}
```

kafka.hocon:

```
{ 
        kafka-clients : {
          enable : {
            auto : {
              commit : false
            }
          }
          bootstrap : {
            servers : "localhost:9092"
          }
          client : {
            id : client-1
          }
          group : {
            id : group-1
          }
        }
  akka : {
    kafka : {
      consumer : {
        poll-interval : 50ms
        poll-timeout : 50ms
        stop-timeout : 30s
        commit-timeout : 15s
        commit-time-warning : 1s
        commit-refresh-interval : infinite
        buffer-size : 128
        use-dispatcher : akka.kafka.default-dispatcher
        kafka-clients : {
          enable : {
            auto : {
              commit : false
            }
          }
          bootstrap : {
            servers : "localhost:9092"
          }
          client : {
            id : client-1
          }
          group : {
            id : group-1
          }
        }
        wait-close-partition : 500ms
        position-timeout : 5s
        offset-for-times-timeout : 5s
        metadata-request-timeout : 5s
        eos-draining-check-interval : 30ms
        partition-handler-warning : 5s
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an issue and a MR with a bugfix here:
https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Streams.Kafka/issues/275